# Making svg image fluid

Tags: html, css, svg, fluid-layout

Im trying to make my svg image in a fluid website so i need it to rescale when the browser is smaller/bigger, but im not having much success. Any suggestions would be really apreciated
Thanks!
here´s my code:

```
<div class="five columns" id="logo">

    <svg width="300" height="160">
        <image xlink:href="/Users/MaxRuizTagle/Desktop/guardado por illustrator/logoprobando.svg" src="" width="270" height="200"/>
    </svg>

</div>
```

css:

```
#logo {
        position: absolute;
        top:-35px;
    }
```

Comment: Scaling when resizing can be done via JS code, or use of percentages with width/height and/or @media queries, usually defined in the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can set a `height` and `width` on an SVG, you really should be setting a viewbox before resizing ...

```
<svg width="300" height="160" viewBox="0 0 300 160">
```

... this will ensure that the internal scale will be aligned with your defined `height` and `width`.

Here's an awesome article: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html